# Groupby drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a df where the category is separated by underscores.

```
df
    fruit   cat
0   apple   green_heavy_pricy
1   apple   heavy_cheap
2   banana  yellow
3   pear    green
4   banana  brown_raw_yellow
...
```

I want to create an agg column that gathers all unique information. I tried `df.groupby("fruit")["cat"].transform("unique")`. Expected Output

```
    fruit   cat                 agg
0   apple   green_heavy_pricy   green_heavy_pricy_cheap
1   apple   heavy_cheap         green_heavy_pricy_cheap
2   banana  yellow              yellow_brown_raw
3   pear    green               green
4   banana  brown_raw_yellow    yellow_brown_raw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with `dict.fromkeys` in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
f = lambda x:  '_'.join(dict.fromkeys('_'.join(x).split('_')))
#alternative solution
#f = lambda x:  '_'.join(pd.unique('_'.join(x).split('_')))
#alternative2 solution
#f = lambda x:  '_'.join(dict.fromkeys(y for y in x for y in y.split('-')))
df['agg'] = df.groupby("fruit")["cat"].transform(f)
print (df)
    fruit                cat                      agg
0   apple  green_heavy_pricy  green_heavy_pricy_cheap
1   apple        heavy_cheap  green_heavy_pricy_cheap
2  banana             yellow         yellow_brown_raw
3    pear              green                    green
4  banana   brown_raw_yellow         yellow_brown_raw
```