# Pandas dataframe IF in a SUM function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

i have two data frame

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
0      20156.51  0.000745          Coinbase      20153.28  0.000200          Coinbase
1      20157.52  0.050000          Coinbase      20152.27  0.051000          Coinbase
2      20158.52  0.000745          Coinbase      20151.28  0.000200          Kraken
3      20158.52  0.050000          FTX           20151.28  0.051000          Coinbase
```

I would like to group the same price, add quantity together and combine the name of the exchange like :

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
0    20156.51  0.000745          Coinbase      20153.28  0.000200          Coinbase
1    20157.52  0.050000          Coinbase      20152.27  0.051000          Coinbase
2    20158.52  0.050745          CoinbaseFTX   20151.28  0.051200       KrakenCoinbase
```

I succeeded using

```
df.groupby(['asks_price', 'bids_price']).sum(False)
```

It's working BUT if this is the same name i dont want to concat it. I dont want CoinbaseCoinbase or KrakenKraken
So i have to include an if in the SUM function , how can i do it
Thanks

Comment: If it's not clear , please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Changing `2: 'Kraken'` to `2: 'Coinbase' for `exchange_name_bid` to generate
# an example that doesn't require concatenation
data = {'asks_price': {0: 20156.51, 1: 20157.52, 2: 20158.52, 3: 20158.52}, 
        'asks_qty': {0: 0.000745, 1: 0.05, 2: 0.000745, 3: 0.05}, 
        'exchange_name_ask': {0: 'Coinbase', 1: 'Coinbase', 2: 'Coinbase', 
                              3: 'FTX'}, 
        'bids_price': {0: 20153.28, 1: 20152.27, 2: 20151.28, 3: 20151.28}, 
        'bids_qty': {0: 0.0002, 1: 0.051, 2: 0.0002, 3: 0.051}, 
        'exchange_name_bid': {0: 'Coinbase', 1: 'Coinbase', 2: 'Coinbase', 
                              3: 'Coinbase'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

res = df.groupby(['asks_price', 'bids_price'], as_index=False).agg(
    {'asks_qty':'sum',
     'bids_qty':'sum',
     'exchange_name_ask': lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()),
     'exchange_name_bid': lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys())
     })

print(res)

   asks_price  bids_price  asks_qty  bids_qty exchange_name_ask  \
0    20156.51    20153.28  0.000745    0.0002          Coinbase   
1    20157.52    20152.27  0.050000    0.0510          Coinbase   
2    20158.52    20151.28  0.050745    0.0512      Coinbase,FTX   

  exchange_name_bid  
0          Coinbase  
1          Coinbase  
2          Coinbase  # no concatenation here
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`df.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and split the functions to be applied to the different columns. I.e. `sum` for columns `'*_qty'`, and a lambda function for columns `'exchange_name_*'` with `dict.fromkeys` nested inside [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). (As mentioned by [`@jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) in the comments, `dict.fromkeys` has better performance than  using [`Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html). Cf. his [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684942/groupby-drop-duplicates/73684958#73684958) elsewhere.)
- Change `','.join` to `''.join`, if you don't want a delimiter. If you want to re-order the columns of `res` so that they match the order of the original `df`, use `res = res.loc[:,df.columns]`.